# Faker Library does not provide keywords after successful installation in PyCharm

Tags: robotframework

I have followed the steps to add and install the `robotframework-faker` library as

```
File->settings->project interpreter
```

However after the installation having completed successfully, I am unable to get faker related keywords.

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens when you try to import the library from the command line?

Comment: What have you tried in order to get the keywords?

Comment: I am not able to  get the keyword like First name Male and First Name Female though i have imported the faker liabrary. Getting below error :- [ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\PytthonExample\Files\Faker1.robot' on line 3: Importing test library 'FakerLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module name
d 'FakerLibrary'
My robot file is like this: - *** Settings ***
Documentation    Suite description
Library     FakerLibrary
*** Test Cases ***
Test1
    ${a}    First Name Male
    log to console  ${a}
    log  ${a}